# Not getting Water from Radiator

Tags: radiator, heat

I moved into my home a few months ago and suspect it's been quite a while since anyone bled the radiators. I've been going around bleeding them for a few days and I'm still getting a lot of air out of some of them and I'm not getting water from any. I'm not even getting water out of the ones that are completely heating up. Should I keep the valve open until water comes out (even if the air has stopped?)

Should I just keep bleeding them until all radiators stop pushing air out? or is there potentially a bigger issue?

Comment: What type of boiler is installed?  Is it a pressurized system?

Comment: *"I'm not even getting water out of the ones that are completely heating up."* Got to wonder if you have steam rather than hot water, for the first thing. The second would be whether you need to open a fill valve on the boiler to add some water. But if it's a steam system it will be considerably different than a hot water system... If it has not had annual service, you might want to have that done and sort out this issue as well.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info (e.g. type of system) before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.